# How to create a seperate class for view with buttons programatically in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am new to Xamarin Forms, i am trying to create a view and add buttons as subviews to the view. I am not able to add child to "View" class. How to add subview/child to "View" class in xamarin programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Layout (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/layouts/)
The easiest way is to use a `StackLayout`: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout/

```cs
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Spacing = 0,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Children = 
    {
        new Button
        {
            Text = "Button 1",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        },
        new Button
        {
            Text = "Button 2",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        },
        new Button
        {
            Text = "Button 3",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        }
    }
}
```